# Is Visual Basic a very useful Programming Language nowadays?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I'm just asking because very big companies such as Apple, Facebook or Electric Arts do not use it. And also I have another question: Is it good to learn Visual Basic or languages such as C, C++, Java, ect?

Thanks.

Comment: programming experience in general is good in my opinion. And now begins the 60 second count down before a mod puts this on hold for being off topic or the like

Comment: I see a lot more job postings for C++ and Java than I do for VB.

Comment: @lurker That's true my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB has many different versions and I would say not to bother learning VB6 but VB.Net would be good if you want to stay with VB (though I prefer C#). Just like any programing language the older it is the less a particular version gets used. I have a worked at a few companies that have most products in .Net but still a few legacy apps in VB6.

As for which to learn that is up to you, I recommend figuring out what kind of software you want to write and then learn what language is used the most for that.

Comment: In the .net realm, C# would be more in current demand in the market, I believe.

Comment: @lurker Yes it is, which is why I use C# but I have seen job postings advertising for VB.Net and they usually pay more since less people know it.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely more jobs for what has become mainstream languages such as C++ or Java. Personally my first exposure to programming was VB and bash, so it really depends on why you want to learn a certain language.